# Maven, configure option is missing

Tags: java, maven

I installed maven on eclipse, its working when I go to the project and do do maven clean, then maven install. But if I go the project and try to go to Configure then as maven project, the option does not appear in my eclipse but in my friends eclipse it appears.

Comment: try restarting eclipse once. Its the root of many problems..!!

Comment: Yes, restarting is the first step!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is designed to run completely stand-alone, so for a quick fix you could just copy over your friend's eclipse folder to your own machine and see if the option appears.

For the long fix, how about reinstalling the maven eclipse plugin software?

http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html

Comment: what I  actually did .... was took my friends project and imported it and enabled maven dependicies and Bam it worked ,,, although on the long run probably I shd reinstall maven